# Products from columns into empty frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two frames. `frame_1` is empty and contains a unique `Sample` column correlating to a `Sample` column in `frame_2`.  I want to populate `frame_1` with products calculated from `frame_2` based on the `Sample` column, then produce a `Max_prod` column. The `val_`, `val_2`, `val_3`, `prod_1`, `prod_2`, `prod_3`, and `Max_prod` columns are all type float.

The frames look like this:

frame_1 before calculating products

```
ID    Sample    prod_1    prod_2    prod_3    Max_prod
0     1         
1     2
```

frame_2

```
ID    Sample    val_1    val_2    val_3  
0     1         1        2        2               
1     1         2        2        2               
2     1         7500     2        7500
3     1         1        1        1
4     1         1        1        1
5     1         1        2500     1
6     1         1        1        1
7     1         1        1        1
8     1         1        1        1
9     1         2        1        1
10    1         1        1        1
11    1         1        1        1
12    1         2        1        1
13    1         1        1        1
14    1         1        1        1
15    1         1        1        1
16    1         2        1        1
17    1         1        1        1
18    1         1        1        1
19    1         1        1        1
20    1         1        1        1
21    2         2        2        2
22    2         3        3        3
23    2         1        1        1
24    2         1        1        1
25    2         1        333.333  1
26    2         1        1        1
27    2         1        1        1
28    2         1        1        1
29    2         1        1        1
30    2         1        1        1
31    2         1        5        370.3704
32    2         5000     4        1
33    2         1        1        1
34    2         1        1        1
35    2         1        1        9
36    2         1        1        1
37    2         1        1        1
38    2         1        1        1
39    2         1        1        1
40    2         1        1        1
41    2         1        1        1
```

output for frame_1 ----->populated

```
ID    Sample    prod_1   prod_2   prod_3   Max_prod
0     1         120000   20000    30000    120000
1     2         30000    40000    20000    40000
```

My code does what I need but the problem is when I expand it up to say 100,000 in the `Sample` column of `frame_1` (ie up to 21,000,000 in the `Sample` column in `frame_2` it takes close to ten minutes. This is OK but it would be better if I could speed this up. Some sort of join? Anyone got any ideas?

```
for sample in frame_1['Sample']:
    mask1 = (sample == frame_1['Sample'])
    mask2 = (sample  == frame_2['Sample'])
    frame_1.loc[mask1, 'prod_1'] = frame_2.loc[mask2, 'val_1'].prod()
    frame_1.loc[mask1, 'prod_2'] = frame_2.loc[mask2, 'val_2'].prod()
    frame_1.loc[mask1, 'prod_3'] = frame_2.loc[mask2, 'val_3'].prod()
frame_1['Max_prod'] = frame1[['val_1', 'val_2','val_3']].max(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the product of `val_X` per `Sample`, try groupby and aggregation.

```
frame_1 = frame_2.groupby('Sample') \
    .agg({'val_1':'prod', 'val_2': 'prod', 'val_3': 'prod'}) \
    .reset_index()
```

### For Pandas >= 0.25

You can name the aggregation.

```
frame_1 = frame_2.groupby('Sample') \
    .agg(prod_1=('val_1','prod'), prod_2=('val_2', 'prod'), prod_3=('val_3', 'prod')) \
    .reset_index()
```

Generally, you want to avoid `for` loop for pandas operation. pandas function's are vectorized, so you can benefit its performance.

Comment: Thank. I know, I was just unsure how to vectorize getting products like this when I had to do all of them. I will try this.

Comment: I think this is going to work pretty well. I’ll mark it as soon as I run it on 100k. Tried it on 10 and it was a hell of a lot faster than even 5k with the for loop

Comment: 10 min down to 1.4 seconds. Beautiful. Thank you!